# Determining search variable when using Inverse Distance Weighted Interpolation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, inverse-distance-weighted

When using IDW interpolation in ArcGIS, how should I determine the number of nearest input sample points to be used to perform interpolation?

The default number is 12, but it may be incorrect.

Comment: When you tested using 12 was there something in the results that made you think that number may be "incorrect"?